# android drawing on canvas. Access canvas outside of onDraw

Tags: android, android-canvas, zooming, pinchzoom, android-bitmap

In order to access canvas outside of onDraw() I do this:

```
 private Canvas canvas;


 public MyView(Context context, Paint paint) {
     super(context);

     canvas = new Canvas();
 }

 @Override
 protected final void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     canvas.save();

     this.canvas = canvas;
}
```

And after that I use it:

```
 private class myScaleListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

     @Override
     public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
     }
 }
```

Is there a better way to do this?

When I call `canvas.setMatrix(matrix)` from `onDraw()` the drawing is being shifted.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is there a problem in current method? Why are you looking for a better way?

Comment: No, there is no problem, but I think that is a bad approach doing it this way. I make a canvas a class variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you switch some things around, it'll look better:

```
private Canvas canvas;

public MyView(Context context, Paint paint) {
    super(context);
    canvas = null;
}

@Override
protected final void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    canvas.save();
}

private class myScaleListener extends SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {<br/>

  @Override
  public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    if(canvas != null) {
       canvas.setMatrix(matrix);
    }
  }
}
```

See if it works, I think it should.

Comment: user2413303, Thank you much!!! Is there any way to obtain the canvas from onScale method without making canvas a class variable??? Thanks much in advance!!!

Comment: I don't think there is, and I really don't think it would look better at all.

Comment: I think there is a possibility to change "extends View" to "extends SurfaceView". This way I will be able to obtain the canvas in a nice way. I do this, but I obtain a black screen.

Comment: :|  i can't help with SurfaceView unfortunately. I tried using it, but it was too confusing with all the invalidations and locks. But yes, that could help and work.